# How do I get multitouch working on a on Asus EEE pc 1215n?

Tags: 10.10, multi-touch, eeepc

Just installed fresh ubuntu 10.10 on my eee pc 1215n and found that multitouch doesn't work properly?
Is there any specific driver?
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wiki might be of some help: [Synaptics Touchpad](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad). Here is one more wiki, it has specific guidelines for EEE PC: [Ubuntu community documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EeePC/1001P)

Answer (score 0):

That's the only info you need (I saw that the script from time to time won't work on 10.04): https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad#Enabling%20True%20Multitouch